# Using the method pushViewController:animated: will lead to memory leak in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

I use the following code in my app

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.singleTopicViewController animated:YES];
```

but I found that it would create a new "singleTopicViewController" even when I clicked the same button.
Will it lead to memory leak in iOS?
How to release the controller which will not be used?

Comment: This code alone should not create a new singleTopicViewController - it should use the same one all the time. There must be some place in your code that does reinitialise the singleTopicViewController property each time you pres the button, eg in the property's setter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use ARC in your project, memory leaks will not follow. You don't need to free the memory manually. Of course, if you do not make heavy reference to each new controller,but it would be insane. =)

Answer (score 0):

use the singleton pattern to do something like this:

```
-(SingleTopicViewController *)singleTopicVC
{
     if (self.singleTopicViewController == nil) {
         self.singleTopicViewController = [[SingleTopicViewController alloc] init];
     }
     return self.singleTopicViewController;
}
```